# Lista Encadeada

Tags: c

estou com dificuldade de entender esse conceito de ponteiro struct dentro da struct, com funciona? como armazena o endereço do próximo elemento infinitamente?

```
typedef struct elemento Elemento;  
struct elemento  
{  
    int info;  
    Elemento* prox;  
};  

Elemento* lst_cria (void)  
{  
    return NULL;  
} 

Elemento* lst_insere (Elemento* lst, int val)  
{  
      Elemento* novo = (Elemento*) malloc(sizeof(Elemento));  
    novo->info = val;  
    novo->prox = lst;  
    return novo;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Um ponteiro nada mais é que um endereço na memória.

Quando você declara um ponteiro numa struct, seja ele para a própria struct ou pra qualquer outra coisa, até você atribuir algum valor a ele, é só um número aleatório (ou 0, dependendo do sistema/compilador/whatever, mas não conte com isso).

Então sim, na prática você pode criar endereços para os próximos elementos infinitamente (que é o ponto da lista ligada, afinal), isso só não acontece de forma automática (que imagino que seja sua preocupação). Para cada elemento que você quiser colocar na lista você precisa alocar a memória (o `malloc` ali) e colocar isso no ponteiro no último elemento que você tinha.

**TL;DR**: Não, o ponteiro não gera uma struct infinita. O ponteiro ali é só um número.

Answer (score 0):

Você quer inserir infinitamente?

você pode fazer o que o amigo acima disse, alocar memória como fez e colocar isso dentro de uma estrutura de repetição (com uma condição pra sair dela). Aí você aloca um espaço toda vez e insere um valor. Quando fiz na faculdade, criei um menu com as opções e coloquei ele dentro de um while, aí toda vez que rodava, alocava memória e eu poderia inserir à vontade, até escolher a opção de sair. Se não entender eu tento explicar melhor. Estrutura de dados é o terror da galera.